# How to add resources to MacOS Bundle in CMake

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, bundle

Currently I add resources like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(Example VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX C)

set(SRC
    src/main.cpp
)
set(SHADERS
    shaders/example.frag
)
set(MODELS
    models/cube.obj
)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${SRC}
    ${SHADERS}
    ${MODELS}
)

if(APPLE)
    # Bundling macOS application
    set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
        BUNDLE True
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME}
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION}
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.${PROJECT_NAME}
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_ICON_FILE AppIcon
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION}
    )
    set_source_files_properties(${SHADERS}
        PROPERTIES
        MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION "Resources/shaders"
    )
    set_source_files_properties(${MODELS}
        PROPERTIES
        MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION "Resources/models"
    )
    install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} BUNDLE DESTINATION .)
endif()
```

I understand that `add_executable` is getting a bit abused in here but even the official CMake example https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RESOURCE.html adds resource files like that and otherwise my resource files won't get copied into my .app folder.

With my shader files this works flawlessly though but I get a problem when adding models. Then CMake fails with following error:
`[build] ld: unknown file type in '.../models/cube.obj'`

I understand that this occurs because `add_executable` does nothing else than passing the files to the compiler and the compiler probably doesn't like the `.obj`extension.

My current solution is to simply rename my models, for example to `models/cube.model` but this is very unsatisfactory, is there another way to add resources that is more elegant? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was solved here: https://discourse.cmake.org/t/how-to-add-resources-to-macos-bundle/

The solution was to mark the resource files as `HEADER_FILE_ONLY`